# Chart.js Tooltip not showing all values of x-axis datasets in a specific point in line chart, issue with mode: 'index'

Tags: javascript, chart.js, svelte, sveltekit

I used to use below configuration in Chart.js@2.9.4 in SvelteKit and it was showing all values of the dataset in a specific point of line chart. [[REPL LINK]](https://svelte.dev/repl/c4ef578c34564d06a1278519be9a4b98?version=3.49.0)

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },
    responsive: true
}
```

The output was:

[image]

After upgrading chart to chart.js@3.8.0 it isn't showing all datasets at one point as above configuration.

This is the output in chart.js@3:

[image]

I am expecting it to show all datasets at one point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are updating to a new major version which has multiple major breaking changes, so is the tooltip config moved from the `options.tooltips` namespace to the `options.plugins.tooltip` namespace, if you change this it works as expected. I suggest you read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html) first since there are more things changed that will break if you only update the version number.

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```