# Chart.js - parsing Object Array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart.js version - 3.8.0 (latest)

Hi all

Losing my mind with this at the moment. I have been able to successfully display the chart once. Since then it is failing to render and I have no idea why.

I have built an object array prior (counts lines in multiple csv files) to declaring the chart options and then passed this array in according to the examples on the chart js website.

I have output to console to ensure that the data is being loaded correctly and everything looks ok. Could someone please cast an eye over the code below and point out anything obvious?

```
const data = YTDTable; 

var ctx1 = document.getElementById('YTD').getContext('2d');

var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: data,
        label: "Tickets to Date"
    }]
},
options: {
    parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'month',
        yAxisKey: 'count'
    }
},
    });
```

This is the dataset output of **console.log(myChart1.data)** which is executed after the above codeblock:

```
{
    "datasets": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "month": "January",
                    "count": 1629
                },
                {
                    "month": "February",
                    "count": 1832
                },
                {
                    "month": "April",
                    "count": 1626
                },
                {
                    "month": "May",
                    "count": 2034
                },
                {
                    "month": "March",
                    "count": 1802
                },
                {
                    "month": "June",
                    "count": 1585
                }
            ],
            "label": "Test"
        }
    ],
    "labels": []
}
```

I just don't understand why the above code isn't working. Any help is much appreciated

The chart output on screen:
[chart image - can't embed images yet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAgfu.png)

Comment: I'd say you have too many properties in your data.  Other examples suggest it should look like `data: [40, 47, 44, 38, 27, 31, 25]`,  or in your case `data: [1629, 1832, 1626...]`

Comment: According to the examples on chartjs.org this should be fine:

`type: 'bar',
data: {datasets: [{
data: [{id: 'Sales', nested: {value: 1500}}, {id: 'Purchases', nested: {value: 500}}]
}]
},
options: {parsing: {xAxisKey: 'id',yAxisKey: 'nested.value'}
}`

Comment: I'm suspicious of whether that's the case for two reasons: 1, it's not working for you and 2) how would the library know which data point to graph - month or count? Maybe that should work but I've never seen it done that way. Perhaps an example to reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/73054451/1544886

Comment: Can you provide the link to that example

Comment: That's what is confusing me, all the data did display properly but for some reason it has since stopped

Comment: [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties)

Comment: The data structure in the examples is different to what you have above

Comment: They have `nested: {value: 1500}`.  You have `"count": 1629`

Comment: after doing some more checks due to the above comment I can see that the data being parsed is correct structure wise, the reason for the double quotes in my above post is due to the way i copied and pasted from the console output. I tested this by pasting the same dataset into my page and then outputting to console and copying the output into notepad

Comment: It seems to be working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/Lmfj2ry4/1/

Answer (score 1):

OK, SO

I figured out what the problem was. The code does work. It just isn't rendering it straight away for some reason. If I resize the window it draws it to screen....

Oh well. Can fix that. Thanks for looking

**UPDATE**

I have identified the cause for the delay in the drawing of the chart and decide to update the answer in case anyone has a similar problem.

My chart code appeared to be executing before the data collected in YTDTable had finished. II have now removed the code block responsible for the data collection from the javascript file and placed it in a script block in the index page instead.

This causes the data collection to execute long before the chart code executes.